# Mock all methods except one in JUnit test with Mockk llibrary

Tags: junit, mockk

How to mock or spy some methods but use real logic of another method in the same class using Mockk library?

Here is a simplified logic of parent-child classes that I have:

```
open class Parent() {
    var condition = true
    fun method1() {
        if (condition) {
            method2("bum")
        } else {
            method3(41)
        }
    }

    fun method2(someStr: String): String {
        //some complicated logic
        return "some result"
    }

    fun method3(someInt: Int): Int {
        //some complicated logic
        return 42
    }
}

class Child: Parent() { }
```

And a test that I want to have:

```
 @Test
 fun `when condition is true, it should call method2`() {
    clearAllMocks()

    val child: Child = mockk()
    child.condition = true
    every { child.method2(any()) } returns "something"
    every { child.method3(any()) } returns 11

    child.method1()

    verify(exactly = 1) { child.method2(any()) }
}
```

Of course this logic for testing doesn't work. But how I can call real `method1` but mock `method2` and `method3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to mock some methods with Mockk except one:

```
    @Test
    fun `when condition is true, it should call method2`() {
        clearAllMocks()

        val child: Child = spyk()
        every { child.condition } returns true
        every { child.method2(any()) } returns "something"
        every { child.method3(any()) } returns 11
        //every { child.method1() } answers { callOriginal() } - this works with and without this line

        child.method1()

        verify(exactly = 1) { child.method2(any()) }
    }
```

It's possible to do with `spyk` and it's obligatory to mock a behavior of methods that need to be mocked with `every`.
For non-mocked method add nothing or to be sure that its behavior is unambiguous - you can add `callOriginal`